# How can I find information about a file from logical cluster number in NTFS/FAT32?

Tags: windows, ntfs, fat32, defragmentation

I am trying to defragment a single file through Windows defragmentation API ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363911(VS.85).aspx ) but if there is no free space block large enough for my file I would like to move other parts of files to make room for it.

The linked article mentions moving parts of other files but I can't find any information about how to find out which files to move. From the free space bitmap I can find an almost large enough space and I know the logical cluster numbers surrounding it, but from this I can't find out which files are surrounding it and a handle to the files is required to do FSCTL_MOVE_FILE which moves parts of files.

Is there any way, through the API or by parsing the MFT, to find out what file a logical cluster number is part of, and what virtual cluster number in the file corresponds to the logical cluster number found through the bitmap?

Answer (score 2):

The slow but compatible method is to recursively scan all directories for files, and use the [FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364572(VS.85).aspx). Then scan the resulting VCN-LCN mapping for the cluster in question.

Another option would be to query the USN Journal of the drive to get the File Reference IDs, then use [FSCT_GET_NTFS_FILE_RECORD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364568(VS.85).aspx) to get the $MFT file record.

I'm currently working on a simple Defrag program (written in Java) with the aim to pack files of a directory (e.g. all files of a large game) close together to reduce loading times and loading lags.

I use a faster method to retrieve the file mappings on the NTFS or FAT32 drive.

I parse the $MFT file directly (the format has some pitfalls), or the FAT32 file allocation table along with the directories.

The trick is to open the drive (e.g. "c:") with FileCreate for fully shared GENERIC read. The resulting handle can then be read with FileRead and FileSeek on a byte granularity. This works only in administrator mode (or elevated).

On NTFS, the $MFT might be fragmented and is a bit tricky to locate it from the boot sector info. I use the FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS on the C:\$MFT file to get its clusters.

On FAT32, one must parse the boot sector to locate the FAT table and the cluster containing root directory file. You need to parse the directory entries and recursively locate the clusters of the sub-directories.

Comment: As an update, Windows 7 has `FSCTL_LOOKUP_STREAM_FROM_CLUSTER` which seems to do just what the OP wants, in one operation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no O(1) way of mapping from block # to file.  You need to walk the entire MFT looking for files that contain that block.

Of course, in a live system, once you've read that data it's out-of-date and you must be prepared for failures in the move data FSCTL.